# The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action while adding a permission

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

By using below code i am trying to add `publish_actions` permission to app.

```
if (state.name().equalsIgnoreCase("OPENED")) {
            try {
                Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session,
                        "", new Request.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    List<String> permissions = session
                                            .getPermissions();

                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "SessionStatusCallback -> CurrentPermissions "
                                                    + permissions);
                                    getUserInformation(session);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                request.executeAsync();
```

But i am getting below response

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action}, isFromCache:false}
```

I am able to fetch user information but not able to add permission and post a wall.

Could you please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Best Regards